# htaccess: remove selected key=value pair from query string

Tags: .htaccess

I've been trying to work my head around this but my .htaccess powers just aren't as good as I thought. I have this sample query string:

```
http://mycoolsite.com/store.php?a=apples&type=fresh&b=banana
```

Is it possible to do this using .htaccess:

1. Check if `type=fresh` exists. If not then redirect to page index.php
2. If *type=fresh* exists, remove it but retain the rest of the query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to match against the query string. In your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)type=fresh&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2   [L,R]
```

This will make it so if someone enters http://mycoolsite.com/store.php?a=apples&type=fresh&b=banana in the browser, their browser will get redirected to http://mycoolsite.com/store.php?a=apples&b=banana . If you want the redirect to happen internally (so the browser's location bar doesn't change), remove the `,R` in the brackets at the end of the RewriteRule.

Comment: Thanks, I tested this over at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and the resulting URL became `http://mycoolsite.com/store.php?%1%2`. Shouldn't it be *http://mycoolsite.com/store.php?a=apples&b=banana*?

Comment: %1 and %2 are backreferences to the previous RewriteCond. This works in my .htaccess file.