# remove part of the end of a URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a URL to remove the end of a URL. I know there are many questions about this already, but I don't know enough to adapt the rewrites to my application.

Here is the URL:
https://www.geoexchange.com.au/gain-resources-library/?mdocs-cat=mdocs-cat-8&att=null

I need to remove "&att=null" from any URL that includes that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: SO is _not_ a free code writing service. If you need someone to write code for you then please hire a (payed) programmer. This is a community to get help. We are here to help you with issues you get stuck with. For that you need to show the code you are working with, so your attempts to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess: remove selected key=value pair from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161580/htaccess-remove-selected-key-value-pair-from-query-string)